# WakeLockWrapper Causing Memory Leak

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I am implementing a call answer screen. In this screen, I am using both proximity sensor and power manager wake lock to create the effect of screen turning off when the phone is close to your face. I've managed to implement the feature, however it is causing memory leak. Since I detected the leak when the fragment is still simple and contains few code, I've removed several classes and functions to trace and confirm the cause of the leak. I've managed to narrow down the cause of the leak to PowerManager.WakeLock.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbL4a.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbL4a.png)]

[image]

this is the code that I use to implement the feature in the fragment. I've tried to release the wake lock on multiple point in fragment lifecycle, however it still causes memory leak.

```
override val sensorManager: SensorManager
        get() = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    override var proximitySensor: Sensor? = null
    override val powerManager: PowerManager =
        requireContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    override val lock: PowerManager.WakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
        PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK,
        PROXIMITY_WAKE_LOG_TAG
    )

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        proximitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY)

        activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback {
            activity?.finishAndRemoveTask()
        }

    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        proximitySensor?.let { proximity ->
            sensorManager.apply {
                registerListener(
                    this@AnswerFragment,
                    proximity,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
                )
            }
        }
    }

override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        if (lock.isHeld) {
            lock.release()
        }
    }

override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        proximitySensor = null
        if (lock.isHeld) {
            lock.release()
        }
        _binding = null
    }

override fun onDestroy() {
        if (lock.isHeld) {
            lock.release()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if (event?.values?.get(0) == 0.0f) {
            // Object is near phone, turn off screen
            lock.acquire()
        } else {
            // Object is not near phone, turn on screen
            if (lock.isHeld) {
                lock.release()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {}
```

As a side note: I am also getting this error in my log

> WakeLock finalized while still held

Comment: That's coming from something in `com.android.tools.profiler`. Do you get this if you run your app normally, not from the IDE?

Comment: @CommonsWare Hey thanks for looking into this. I am testing the app on my phone, not from the emulator if that is what you are asking.

Comment: No, I am asking how you run the app. As a developer, you could run the app from the IDE (e.g., Android Studio). Or, you could run the app the way your users probably do, by tapping the launcher icon. If you only get this leak when your process was started by the IDE, and you do not get it when your process was started normally, then my guess is that this leak is being caused by a profiler in the IDE.

Comment: Hey again. Thanks for clarifying. I am running the app from IDE. The funny thing is, Leak Canary only detect the leak when I run the profiler in IDE, and it does not trigger the leak when I did not run the profiler. I think this is the reason you mentioned "That's coming from something in com.android.tools.profiler"? This is new to me, do you mind explaining a bit more? Or if there is any link to an article or documentation that can help me understand more about this? Leak coming from android profiler seems a bit ridiculous? it is a tool to monitor memory leak but it also causes memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. See [the LeakCanary issue](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/2454) and [the underlying tools issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260459152). For now, I recommend that you consider it to be a false positive, and ignore the leak.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Seems like it caused some commotion... Really appreciate the help. Would've wasted a lot of time solving this is you didn't mention this.